# How to download CDT for Eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-14.04

I am using **eclipse 3.8**. It is an unnamed version. From where can one download the CDT for eclipse 3.8 ? The official downloads link http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php does not provide CDT for 3.8. Updating my eclipse IDE is not an option because I am using UBUNTU 14.04

Comment: eclipse > 3.8 is not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 ??? Please download the 4.4 and tell us why you don't want to use it. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-44/lunar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution: there is an official [`eclipse-cdt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/eclipse-cdt) package in Ubuntu 14.04.

However, instead of doing that, I would recommend that you simply download the Eclipse tarball from the official website instead of using the Ubuntu package. There are at least two advantages:

- Your downloaded version of Eclipse will nearly always be more up-to-date than the packaged version;
- You can install multiple instances of Eclipse, with different sets of plugins (e.g. one for Java, and another for C++);